# A movie that (possible ends with) a steampunk/iron clad boat with explosive cannonballs

Tags: story-identification, steampunk, western

A movie (possible tv series), that ended with an iron clad boat with explosive cannonballs that would be ignited by a orange glowing cannonball, pretty sure it was live action, but not sure. The rest of the movie may or may not have been steampunk. I'm pretty sure the boat was about to fire upon a city before the hero stopped it.

Comment: Possible on satellite TV, not really sure, all I know is that I watched it at my own house, not somebody elses.

Answer (score 2):

not really steampunk but you could get that vibe maybe [Jonah Hex](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1075747/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

Boat and city at the end.

Orange cannon ball things.

live action.

Maybe steampunkish if you squint -shrug-

Comment: yes. they fire them and then fire some sort of triggering cannon ball and this sets the earlier ones off. i was gonna say wild wild west because that is the same sort "futuristic/old west" kind of gimmick the original show had and the will smith movie had. steam punk is accurate -- devices we would have trouble building even now but powered by steam. steam power was considered a true marvel in the 19th century -- this is mentioned in david copperfield.

Comment: This is 100% it, thank you sir, you have spared me from a life of torment in trying to find this movie.